# Error when I try to create OrderItem records Insert failed. INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, pricebookentry, orderitem

I'm trying to create a visualforce page where a user can create multiple OrderItem records at the same time.

The error that I get is

> OrderItem records Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: [] -
>   Line: 138

I have 2 methods in the controller

1. `obtenerProductos()` shows records of PriceBookEntry
2. `insertarProductos()` checks these records and create records of
   OrderItem object but it doesn't work.

The other objects that I'm using are Opportunity, Order, PriceBook2 and Product2.

I think the problem is with the field `PricebookEntryId` of the variable `prAux`.

Visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="CotizadorPrincipalController" lightningStylesheets="true" docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Detalles de la Oportunidad">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >Nombre<apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Name }"/></apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Fecha_del_evento__c }"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Total_de_Servicios_con_IVA__c }"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Espacio__c }"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <!-- Botón de regreso a la página de la Oportunidad -->
            <a style="float:right;"><apex:commandButton value="Regresar a la Oportunidad" action="{!volver}"/></a>
        </apex:form> 
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Seleccione el Servicio:" collapsible="false">           
                <apex:selectList value="{!servicioSeleccionado}" size="1">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="form"/>
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!orders}"/>
                </apex:selectList><br/>

                <apex:commandButton value="Show Service" action="{!show}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Mostrar Productos" action="{!obtenerProductos}"/>           
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Seleccione los productos a añadir:" columns="1">  
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listaProductosParaAnadir}" var="wrpProductos">          
                <apex:column ><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrpProductos.check}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!wrpProductos.productosParaAnadir.Product2.Name}"/>
                <apex:column headerValue="Precio por Unidad"><apex:inputField value="{!wrpProductos.productosParaAnadir.UnitPrice}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Cantidad"><apex:input type="number" value="{!wrpProductos.cantidad}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!wrpProductos.productosParaAnadir.Product2.IVA__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Añada productos no existentes en la base de datos:">        
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listaProductosParaAnadirNoExistentes}" var="wrpProductosNoExist">
                <apex:column ><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrpProductosNoExist.check}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column ><apex:inputField value="{!wrpProductosNoExist.productosParaAnadir.Product2.Name}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Precio por Unidad"><apex:inputField value="{!wrpProductosNoExist.productosParaAnadir.UnitPrice}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Cantidad"><apex:input type="number" value="{!wrpProductosNoExist.cantidad}"/></apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="IVA"><apex:inputField value="{!wrpProductosNoExist.productosParaAnadir.Product2.IVA__c}"/></apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>        
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:commandButton value="Insertar Productos" action="{!insertarProductos}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class CotizadorPrincipalController {
    private final Opportunity opp;
    private Map<String, Id> ordersMap;
    private Map<String, Id> priceBookEntriesMap;
    public String servicioSeleccionado {get;set;}
    private String BASE_URL = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/';
    private String BASE_URL2 = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/';
    public List<OrderItem> listaProductos {get;set;}
    public boolean check {get;set;}
    public List<ProductosWrapper> listaProductosParaAnadir {get;set;}
    public List<ProductosWrapper> listaProductosParaAnadirNoExistentes {get;set;}

    //Clase del Wrapper de Productos del objeto OrderItem, de momento no se usa


    //Clase del Wrapper de Productos del objeto PriceBookEntry
    public class ProductosWrapper{
        public PriceBookEntry productosParaAnadir {get;set;}
        public Boolean check {get;set;}
        public Integer cantidad {get; set;}

        public productosWrapper(PriceBookEntry pbEntry){
            productosParaAnadir = pbEntry.clone (false, false, false, false);
            check = false;
            cantidad = 0;
        }
    }

    public CotizadorPrincipalController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
        this.ordersMap = new Map<String, Id>();
        this.servicioSeleccionado = '';
        this.listaProductos = new List<OrderItem>();
        check = false;
        listaProductosParaAnadir = new List<ProductosWrapper>();
        listaProductosParaAnadirNoExistentes = new List<ProductosWrapper>();
        system.debug('BASE_URL = ' + BASE_URL);

        List<Order> ordersList = [SELECT Id, Name from Order where Oportunidad__c =: this.opp.Id];
        this.servicioSeleccionado = ordersList.get(0).Name;

        for(Order o: ordersList) {
            this.ordersMap.put(o.Name, o.Id);
        }        
    }


    public void obtenerProductos(){
        List<PriceBookEntry> listaPlantillasProductos = new List<PriceBookEntry>();
        this.priceBookEntriesMap = new Map<String,Id>();
        listaProductosParaAnadir.clear();

        Opportunity oppActual = [SELECT Id, Espacio__c, Fecha_del_evento__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: this.opp.Id];
        Integer yearEvento = oppActual.Fecha_del_evento__c.year(); 
        String yearEventoToString = String.valueOf(yearEvento);
        System.debug('Fecha del evento = ' + oppActual.Fecha_del_evento__c);
        System.debug('Año de variable year = ' + yearEvento);
        System.debug('Año de variable year = ' + yearEventoToString);

        listaPlantillasProductos = [SELECT UnitPrice, Product2.Name, Product2.IVA__c, Product2.Family, Product2Id, PriceBook2Id, PriceBook2.Espacio__c, PriceBook2.Ano__c 
                                    FROM PriceBookEntry
                                    WHERE PriceBook2.Espacio__c != null AND PriceBook2.Espacio__c =: oppActual.Espacio__c 
                                    AND PriceBook2.Ano__c =: yearEventoToString];


        System.debug('listaPlantillasProductos.size(): ' + listaPlantillasProductos.size());

        if(!listaPlantillasProductos.isEmpty()){
            for(PriceBookEntry pbe : listaPlantillasProductos){
                this.priceBookEntriesMap.put(pbe.Product2.Name, pbe.Id);
            }
            ProductosWrapper wrp;
            for (PriceBookEntry pbe : listaPlantillasProductos){
                wrp = new productosWrapper(pbe);
                if(pbe.Product2.Name == 'varios'){
                    listaProductosParaAnadirNoExistentes.add(wrp);
                }else{
                    listaProductosParaAnadir.add(wrp);
                }

                System.debug('PriceBookEntry pbe Name: ' + pbe.Product2.Name);
            }
            for(ProductosWrapper pw : listaProductosParaAnadirNoExistentes){
                System.debug('Nombre del producto NO existente = ' + pw.productosParaAnadir.Product2.Name);
            }
            for(ProductosWrapper pw : listaProductosParaAnadir){
                System.debug('Nombre del producto Sí existente = ' + pw.productosParaAnadir.Product2.Name);
            }
        }
    }


    public void insertarProductos(){
        List<OrderItem> listProductosServicioInsertar = new List<OrderItem>();

        for(ProductosWrapper listado : listaProductosParaAnadir){
            if(listado.cantidad > 0 && listado.cantidad != null){
                System.debug('listado.cantidad = ' + listado.cantidad);             
                OrderItem prAux = new OrderItem();
                prAux.Quantity = listado.cantidad;
                system.debug('prAux.Quantity = ' + prAux.Quantity);
                prAux.UnitPrice = listado.productosParaAnadir.UnitPrice;
                system.debug('prAux.UnitPrice = ' + prAux.UnitPrice);
                prAux.IVA__c = listado.productosParaAnadir.Product2.IVA__c;
                system.debug('prAux.IVA__c = ' + prAux.IVA__c);
                prAux.OrderId = this.OrdersMap.get(this.servicioSeleccionado);
                system.debug('prAux.OrderId = ' + prAux.OrderId);
                prAux.Oportunidad__c = this.opp.Id;
                system.debug('prAux.Oportunidad__c = ' + prAux.Oportunidad__c);

                //prAux.PricebookEntryId = listado.productosParaAnadir.Id; //Aquí falla ya que no existe el id
                System.debug('this.priceBookEntriesMap.get(listado.productosParaAnadir.Product2.Name) = ' + this.priceBookEntriesMap.get(listado.productosParaAnadir.Product2.Name));
                system.debug('listado.productosParaAnadir.Product2.Name = ' + listado.productosParaAnadir.Product2.Name);
                prAux.PricebookEntryId = this.priceBookEntriesMap.get(listado.productosParaAnadir.Product2.Name);
                System.debug('prAux.PricebookEntryId = ' + prAux.PricebookEntryId);

                system.debug('listado.productosParaAnadir.Id = ' + listado.productosParaAnadir.Id);
                listProductosServicioInsertar.add(prAux);
            }
        }
        try {
            if(!listProductosServicioInsertar.isEmpty()){
                insert listProductosServicioInsertar;
            }
        }catch (Exception Exc){
            System.debug('##Error: '+exc.getMessage() + ' - Line: '+exc.getLineNumber());
        }

    }

    public List<SelectOption> getOrders() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();      

        for (String key: this.ordersMap.keySet()) { 
            options.add(new SelectOption(key, key));
        }        
        return options;
    }


    public PageReference show() {
        String serviceUrl = 'https://grupomonico--devconfigu.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Order/[SERVICE_ID]/view';
        serviceUrl = serviceUrl.replace('[SERVICE_ID]', this.ordersMap.get(this.servicioSeleccionado));     
        PageReference retURL = new PageReference(serviceUrl);
        retURL.setRedirect(true);
        return retURL;
    }

    //Método del botón 'Volver a la Oportunidad'
    public PageReference volver() { 
        String serviceUrl = BASE_URL2 + this.opp.Id;
        PageReference retURL = new PageReference(serviceUrl);
        retURL.setRedirect(true);
        return retURL;
    }

    //Método temporal, para borrar
    public List<OrderItem> getProductosAnadidos(){
        system.debug('método getProductosAnadidos, this.servicioSeleccionado: ' + this.servicioSeleccionado);

        system.debug('método getProductosAnadidos, this.ordersMap.get(this.servicioSeleccionado): ' + this.ordersMap.get(this.servicioSeleccionado));
        this.listaProductos = [SELECT Id, Product2.Name, UnitPrice, Quantity, TotalPrice, IVA__c, Precio_Total_con_IVA__c FROM OrderItem
                               WHERE OrderId =: this.ordersMap.get(this.servicioSeleccionado)];
        return listaProductos;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your `System.debug` statements show? Does `prAux` have a value for `PricebookEntryId`?

Comment: I think I found the problem. I found that order has a Pricebook2Id field that need to be populate to create OrderItem records linked to it.

Comment: You can answer your question and accept it as the answer to help others looking at this.

Comment: thanks for your help Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem. I found that order has a Pricebook2Id field that need to be populate to create OrderItem records linked to it.